# Unwanted different fancypages

Tags: fancybox

Would someone please check following code and let me know why there is different page style in pages. In fact, I want to whole pages be like the third page but I don't know why I have narrower box in first and second page.
[image]

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
%\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym,boldline}
\usepackage{roundbox,graphicx,framed}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[top=10mm, bottom=30mm, left=15mm, right=15mm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc,shapes,snakes,automata,shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\DeclareMathSizes{14}{10}{9}{7} 
\settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Niloofar.ttf}
%\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{B_Nazanin.TTF}
\setdigitfont[Scale=1]{Yas.TTF}
\defpersianfont\titr[Scale=1]{XB Titre.ttf}


\begin{document}
\fancypage{}{%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}%
    \fbox}
\vspace{0.3cm}
%\vspace{0.2cm}


\begin{enumerate}
\item

\begin{align*}
y(t)&=2(A cos\omega_ot-3(Acos\omega_ot)^3= 2Acos \omega_ot-3A^3cos^3\omega_ot\\
&=2Acos \omega_ot-3A^3(\frac{3}{4}cos \omega_ot+\frac{1}{4}cos3\omega_ot)\\
&=2Acos\omega_ot-\frac{9}{4}A^3cos\omega_ot-\frac{3}{4}A^3cos3\omega_ot\\
&= \left(2A-\frac{9}{4}A^3\right)cos\omega_ot-\frac{3}{4}A^3cos3\omega_ot\\
Second-Harmonic &Distortion= 0\%\\
Third-Harmonic &Distortion=\left|\frac{2A-\dfrac{9A^3}{4}}{\dfrac{3A^3}{4}}\right|=
\begin{cases}
300\%, & \text{if}\ A=1 \\
42\%, & \text{if}\ A=2
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\item
\begin{tabular}{ c | c}
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
\begin{align*}
P_{in}&=500 mW=10 log 500=27 dBm\\
P_{out}&=50 mW=10 log 50= 17 dBm\\
P_{g_{in}}&=20 \mu W=10 log (0/02)= -17 dBm\\
L_T&= \alpha l= 2X500 Km= 1000 dB
\end{align*}
}
&
 \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
    \begin{align*}
    P_{out}&=P_{out}+G_{T}+L_{T}\\
    G_{T}&=G_1+G_2\\
    L_T&=L_1+L_2+L_3    
    \end{align*}
}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ c | c}

\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
\begin{align*}
&Section B\\
&P_{g_{in}}=P_{in}+0-L_1\\
&-17=27-L_1 \xrightarrow{~} L_1=44\\
&l_1=\frac{L_1}{\alpha}=22 Km\\
&Section D\\
&l_3=500-(l_1+l_2)=230/5\\
Or\\
&P_{out}=P_{g_{2out}}+0-L_3\\
&P_{g_{2out}}=P_{g_{2in}}+G_1=478 dBm\\
&17=478-L_3 \xrightarrow{~} L_1=461 dB\\
&l_3=\frac{L_3}{\alpha}=230/5 Km
\end{align*}
}
&
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{
\begin{align*}
&Section A\\
&P_{out}=P_{out}+G_{T}+L_{T}\\
&17=27-1000+G_T\\
&G_T=990 \xrightarrow{so} G_1=G_2=495\\
&Section C\\
&P_{g_{2in}}=P_{g_{1out}}+0-L_2\\
&P_{g_{1out}}=P_{g_{2in}}+G_1=478 dBm\\
&-17=478-L_2 \xrightarrow{~} L_1=495 dB\\
&l_2=\frac{L_2}{\alpha}=247 Km
\end{align*}
} 
\end{tabular}

\item 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5, gray, very thin](-8.99,-5.99) grid (8.99,-1.03);
\draw[thick,->] (-8.5,-3.5) -- (-3,-3.5) node[anchor=south west] {t};
\draw[thick,->] (-8.5,-6) -- (-8.5,-1) node[anchor=south west] {$x_c(t)_{DSB}$};

\draw[thick,->] (-2.5,-3.5) -- (3,-3.5) node[anchor=south west] {t};
\draw[thick,->] (-2.5,-6) -- (-2.5,-1) node[anchor=south west] {$x_c(t)_{AM_{\mu=0/5}}$};

\draw[thick,->] (3.5,-3.5) -- (8.5,-3.5) node[anchor=south west] {t};
\draw[thick,->] (3.5,-6) -- (3.5,-1) node[anchor=south west] {$x_c(t)_{AM_{\mu=1}}$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\item 


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dotted] (0,0) node[anchor=south west]{DSB} -- (0,5)  ;
\path (-8,0) node[anchor=south east]{AM} -- (-8,5) ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\item 
سیگنال $x(t)$ در شکل زیر نشان داده شده است. از این سیگنال یکبار برای مدولاسیون فرکانس حامل و بار دیگر برای مدولاسیون فاز همان حامل استفاده شده است. 
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}b{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}}
        \captionof*{×}{}
        الف) رابطه بین $f_\Delta$  و $ \phi_\Delta $  را طوری تعیین کنید که حداکثر فاز سیگنال مدوله شده در هر دو حالت برابر باشد. \\
        \\
        \\
        ب) اگر $f_\Delta=\phi_\Delta=1 $   باشد، حداکثر فرکانس لحظه ایی در هر حالت چقدر است ؟
        &
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {$t$};
        \draw[thick,->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[anchor=south east] {$x(t)$};

        \coordinate (a) at (1,1);
        \coordinate (b) at (2,1);
        \coordinate (c) at (2, -1);
        \coordinate (d) at (3, -1);
        \coordinate (e) at (3,0);

        \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (a);
        \draw[thick] (a) -- (b);
        \draw[thick] (b)-- (c);
        \draw[thick] (c) --(d);
        \draw[thick] (d) -- (e);
        \draw[dotted] (a) -- (1,0);
        \draw[dotted] (0,-1)--(2,-1);
        \draw[dotted] (0, 1) -- (1,1);

        \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}
        \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
        \foreach \y in {-1,0,1}
        \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$}; 
        \end{tikzpicture}   
        %\caption*{Weighted, complete graph $K_H$}
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}



\end{enumerate}

 \begin{center}
\titr  
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that can be compiled without having all your special fonts? This would increase the number of people who can potentially help you.

Comment: I cannot test right now, so cannot really help you, but please beware of difference between math mode and textmode and the different visual output.

Comment: I've added a picture to make my issue more clear.

Comment: Again the question: Can you make a minimal working example (MWE) that can be compiled without having all your special fonts?

Comment: your code is not possible to compile. after its heavy repair i cant reproduce your problem. please, even anything close what you show in figure. please edit your question, add missed package, remove arabic text  (it is not essential to your problem  but doing problem to us which haven't installed this fonts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let mi explain my comment. after repairing your code (as far as i guess what you like to obtain), replace `tabular` environments with `tabularx`, remove use of `\parbox` (which is probably cause of your problems: for width you should use `\linewidth` and not `\textwidth`), correct `tizpicture` size (it was to large), use `siunitx` for units i obtain the following result etc, i obtan the following result:

[image]

(gray lines indicate page layout)

mwe:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\doublespacing
%\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
%\usepackage{marvosym}
%\usepackage{MnSymbol,wasysym,boldline}
%\usepackage{roundbox,graphicx,framed}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[top=10mm, bottom=30mm,
            hmargin=15mm,
            nohead,
            showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, tabularx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{xifthen}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes.gates.logic.US,shapes.gates.logic.IEC,calc,shapes,snakes,automata,shapes.geometric}
%\usepackage{xepersian}
%\DeclareMathSizes{14}{10}{9}{7}
%\settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Niloofar.ttf}
%\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{B_Nazanin.TTF}
%\setdigitfont[Scale=1]{Yas.TTF}
%\defpersianfont\titr[Scale=1]{XB Titre.ttf}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % missed
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}    % new

\begin{document}
%\fancypage{}{%
%    \setlength{\fboxrule}{2pt}%
%    \fbox}
%\vspace{0.3cm}
%\vspace{0.2cm}


\begin{enumerate}
\item

\begin{align*}
y(t)    &=2(A cos\omega_ot-3(Acos\omega_ot)^3= 2Acos \omega_ot-3A^3cos^3\omega_ot\\
        &=2Acos \omega_ot-3A^3(\frac{3}{4}cos \omega_ot+\frac{1}{4}cos3\omega_ot)\\
        &=2Acos\omega_ot-\frac{9}{4}A^3cos\omega_ot-\frac{3}{4}A^3cos3\omega_ot\\
        &= \left(2A-\frac{9}{4}A^3\right)cos\omega_ot-\frac{3}{4}A^3cos3\omega_ot
\text{Second-Harmonic}
        & \text{Distortion} = \SI{0}{\%}    \\
\text{Third-Harmonic}
        & Distortion = \left|\frac{2A-\dfrac{9A^3}{4}}{\dfrac{3A^3}{4}}\right| =
    \begin{cases}
\SI{300}{\%}, & \text{if}\ A=1 \\
 \SI{42}{\%}, & \text{if}\ A=2
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\item   \SI{500}{\watt}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ C | C }
$\begin{aligned}
P_{in}      & = \SI{500}{\milli\watt}=10 \log 500=\SI{27}{dBm}\\
P_{out}     & = \SI{50}{\milli\watt} =10 \log 50= \SI{17}{dBm}\\
P_{g_{in}}  & = \SI{20}{\micro\watt} =10 \log (0/02)= \SI{-17}{dBm}\\
L_T         & = \alpha l = 2\times\SI{500}{\kilo\metre}= \SI{1000}{dB}
\end{aligned}$
&
$\begin{aligned}
    P_{out}&=P_{out}+G_{T}+L_{T}\\
    G_{T}&=G_1+G_2\\
    L_T&=L_1+L_2+L_3
    \end{aligned}$
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ C | C }
$\begin{aligned}
    &   \text{Section B}    \\
    &   P_{g_{in}}=P_{in}+0-L_1\\
    &   -17=27-L_1 \xrightarrow{~} L_1=44\\
    &   l_1=\frac{L_1}{\alpha}=\SI{22}{\kilo\metre}\\
    &   \text{Section D}    \\
    &   l_3=500-(l_1+l_2)=230/5\\
\text{Or}   &   \\
    &   P_{out}=P_{g_{2out}}+0-L_3\\
    &   P_{g_{2out}}=P_{g_{2in}}+G_1= \SI{478}{dBm}\\
    &   17=478-L_3 \xrightarrow{~} L_1=\SI{461}{dB}\\
    &   l_3=\frac{L_3}{\alpha}=\SI{230/5}{\kilo\metre}
\end{aligned}$
&   $\begin{aligned}
    & \text{Section A}  \\
    & P_{out}=P_{out}+G_{T}+L_{T}\\
    & 17=27-1000+G_T\\
    & G_T=990 \xrightarrow{so} G_1=G_2=495\\
    & \text{Section C}\\
    & P_{g_{2in}}=P_{g_{1out}}+0-L_2\\
    & P_{g_{1out}}=P_{g_{2in}}+G_1= \SI{478}{dB}\\
    & -17=478-L_2 \xrightarrow{~} L_1= \SI{495}{dB}\\
    & l_2=\frac{L_2}{\alpha}= \SI{247}{\kilo\metre}
    \end{aligned}$
\end{tabularx}

\item

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5, gray, very thin] (-7.99,-5.99) grid (8.49,-1.03);
\draw[thick,->] (-7.5,-3.5) -- (-3.0,-3.5) node[anchor=south west] {t};
\draw[thick,->] (-7.5,-6)   -- (-7.5,-1)   node[anchor=south west] {$x_c(t)_{DSB}$};

\draw[thick,->] (-2.5,-3.5) -- (3,-3.5)  node[anchor=south west] {t};
\draw[thick,->] (-2.5,-6.0) -- (-2.5,-1) node[anchor=south west] {$x_c(t)_{AM_{\mu=0/5}}$};

\draw[thick,->] (3.5,-3.5) -- (8.5,-3.5) node[anchor=south west] {t};
\draw[thick,->] (3.5,-6.0) -- (3.5,-1)   node[anchor=south west] {$x_c(t)_{AM_{\mu=1}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\item

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dotted] ( 0,0) node[anchor=south west]{DSB} -- (0,5)  ;
\draw[dotted] (-8,0) node[anchor=south west]{AM}  -- (-8,5) ;
\end{tikzpicture}


\item $x(t)$
%سیگنال $x(t)$ در شکل زیر نشان داده شده است. از این سیگنال یکبار برای مدولاسیون فرکانس حامل و بار دیگر برای مدولاسیون فاز همان حامل استفاده شده است.
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{tabular}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}b{\dimexpr0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}}
    \caption{?}% not clear
 %        الف) رابطه بین $f_\Delta$  و $ \phi_\Delta $  را طوری تعیین کنید که حداکثر فاز سیگنال مدوله شده در هر دو حالت برابر باشد. \\
%        \\
%        \\
%        ب) اگر $f_\Delta=\phi_\Delta=1 $   باشد، حداکثر فرکانس لحظه ایی در هر حالت چقدر است ؟
        &
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {$t$};
        \draw[thick,->] (0,-2) -- (0,2) node[anchor=south east] {$x(t)$};

        \coordinate (a) at (1,1);
        \coordinate (b) at (2,1);
        \coordinate (c) at (2, -1);
        \coordinate (d) at (3, -1);
        \coordinate (e) at (3,0);

        \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (a);
        \draw[thick] (a) -- (b);
        \draw[thick] (b)-- (c);
        \draw[thick] (c) --(d);
        \draw[thick] (d) -- (e);
        \draw[dotted] (a) -- (1,0);
        \draw[dotted] (0,-1)--(2,-1);
        \draw[dotted] (0, 1) -- (1,1);

        \foreach \x in {0,1,2,3,4}
        \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
        \foreach \y in {-1,0,1}
        \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption*{Weighted, complete graph $K_H$}
    \end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{enumerate}

% \begin{center}
%\titr
%\end{center}
\end{document}
```

please check, if the introduced changes can help you. at least on this code try to write new mwe, which we will able to test and further help you.

off-topic: to my taste the structure of your document is not clear. you should reconsider it.